# newList = list - self

Tags: python, list

I have an list of objects called character like that:

```
characters=[character(0,0,20,20,keys1),character(50,50,50,50,keys2),character(200,200,100,20,keys1)]
```

where character class is defined as:

```
class character():
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h,keys=keys1):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.keys = keys
        self.vel = 200 /math.sqrt(self.w*self.h)
        self.crashed=False
    # I need an list to use here in a function of my "character" class


 # my list must have all the elements in my initial list but self
```

what I mean is like

`characters[0].myFunction()` must have a list of `[characters[1],characters[2]]`
   which is `characters =[character(50,50,50,50,keys2),character(200,200,100,20,keys1)]`

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear what you are looking for help with.

Comment: Make a copy of your `characters` list, call `.remove(self)` on it?

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass as an argument to your `.myFunction` the full list to know from which list to exclude/filter `self`:

```
class character():

    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h,keys=keys1):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.keys = keys
        self.vel = 200 /math.sqrt(self.w*self.h)
        self.crashed = False

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'charcter({}, {}, {}, {}, {})'.format(
            self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h, self.keys)

    def myFunction(self, characters):
        return [e for e in characters if e != self] 

print(characters[0].myFunction(characters))
```

**output:**

```
[charcter(50, 50, 50, 50, keys2), charcter(200, 200, 100, 20, keys1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I Understand what you want but there are a few issues with your code that I decided to fix for you i guess. The first is to remember just for your sake that when making classes make the first letter upper case. Next your key creation does not make any sense because keys1 doesnt exsist. I assumed it to be a string in my example. Next I created an **str** function for your class so it can output the characters somehow so its not only the memory address. Next I created the function you want but it will be in the format

```
x = myFunc(characters[0], characters)
```

and on top of that if you print x it will give you a list of memory addresses and therefore you must loop through and print each character specifically to see which one it is. Here is the final code.

```
import math

class Character():
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h,keys="keys1"):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.keys = keys
        self.vel = 200 /math.sqrt(self.w*self.h)
        self.crashed=False
    # I need an list to use here in a function of my "character" class
    # my list must have all the elements in my initial list but self

    def __str__(self):
        return "Character x:{}, y:{}, w:{}, h:{}, key:{}".format(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h, self.keys)


def myFunc(chars, characters):
    characters_copy = characters[:]
    if chars in characters_copy:
        ind = characters_copy.index(chars)
        characters_copy.pop(ind)
    return characters_copy





characters = [Character(0,0,20,20), Character(50,50,50,50), Character(200,200,100,20)]
x = myFunc(characters[0], characters)
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

I believe this is somewhat what you wanted, I added the changes so its easier for me and you. But you should be able to work with this.

Comment: Please let me know if this is what you had in mind. Thanks.